# Aggregating Rows Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am quite new to `pandas`. I need to aggregate `'Names'` if they have the same name and then make an average for `'Rating'` and `'NumsHelpful'` (without counting `NaN`). `'Review'` should get concatenated whilst `'Weight(Pounds)'`should remain untouched:

```
col names: ['Brand', 'Name', 'NumsHelpful', 'Rating', 'Weight(Pounds)', 'Review']

Name             'Brand'                             'Name'
1534             Zing Zang                Zing Zang Bloody Mary Mix, 32 fl oz   
1535             Zing Zang                Zing Zang Bloody Mary Mix, 32 fl oz   
1536             Zing Zang                Zing Zang Bloody Mary Mix, 32 fl oz   
1537             Zing Zang                Zing Zang Bloody Mary Mix, 32 fl oz   
1538             Zing Zang                Zing Zang Bloody Mary Mix, 32 fl oz   
1539             Zing Zang                Zing Zang Bloody Mary Mix, 32 fl oz   
1540             Zing Zang                Zing Zang Bloody Mary Mix, 32 fl oz   

        'NumsHelpful'     'Rating'       'Weight'
1534          NaN            2              4.5   
1535          NaN            2              4.5   
1536          NaN            NaN            4.5   
1537          NaN            NaN            4.5   
1538          2              NaN            4.5   
1539          3              5              4.5   
1540          5              NaN            4.5   

                        'Review'
1534                                     Yummy - Delish  
1535  The best Bloody Mary mix! - The best Bloody Ma...  
1536  Best Taste by far - I've tried several if not ...  
1537  Best bloody mary mix ever - This is also good ...  
1538  Outstanding - Has a small kick to it but very ...  
1539   OMG! So Good! - Spicy, terrific Bloody Mary mix!  
1540                      Good stuff - This is the best
```

So the output should be something like this:

```
 'Brand'                'Name'                   'NumsHelpful'    'Rating' 
Zing Zang    Zing Zang Bloody Mary Mix, 32 fl oz     3.33             3

 'Weight'               'Review'
   4.5      Review1 / Review2 / ... / ReviewN
```

How shall I procede? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with dictionary of columns and aggregated functions - columns `Weight` and `Brand` are agregated by `first` - it means first values per groups:

```
d = {'NumsHelpful':'mean', 
     'Review':'/'.join, 
     'Weight':'first',
     'Brand':'first', 
     'Rating':'mean'}
df = df.groupby('Name').agg(d).reset_index()
print (df)
                                  Name  NumsHelpful  \
0  Zing Zang Bloody Mary Mix, 32 fl oz     3.333333   

                                              Review  Weight      Brand  \
0  Yummy - Delish/The best Bloody Mary mix! - The...     4.5  Zing Zang   

   Rating  
0     3.0
```

Also in pandas 0.23.1 pandas version get:

> FutureWarning: 'Name' is both an index level and a column label.
>   Defaulting to column, but this will raise an ambiguity error in a future version

Solution is remove index name `Name`:

```
df.index.name = None
```

Or:

```
df = df.rename_axis(None)
```

---

Another possible solution is not aggregate by `first`, but add these column to `groupby`:

```
d = {'NumsHelpful':'mean',  'Review':'/'.join, 'Rating':'mean'}
df = df.groupby(['Name', 'Weight','Brand']).agg(d).reset_index()
```

Both solutions return same output if per groups there are same values.

EDIT:

If need convert string (object) column to numeric first try convert by `astype`:

```
df['Weight(Pounds)'] = df['Weight(Pounds)'].astype(float)
```

And if it failed use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert non parseable strings to `NaN`s:

```
df['Weight(Pounds)'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Weight(Pounds)'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: I tried using your suggestions but the my error still persists :/

Comment: @StefanoPozzi - are data confidental?

Comment: No but managed to fix it :) had to cast columns that I wanted to contain strings to the string type. Thx for help!

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate with a different function for each column using `groupby` + `agg`, together with a dictionary mapping series to functions. For example:

```
d = {'Rating': 'mean',
     'NumsHelpful': 'mean',
     'Review': ' | '.join,
     'Weight(Pounds)': 'first'}

res = df.groupby('Name').agg(d)
```

Comment: where 'mean' is np.mean or simply the string? Coz when I try to run the code it gives me a 'TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found'

Comment: this is the output 'Brand              object - 
Name               object - 
NumsHelpful       float64 - 
Rating            float64 - 
Weight(Pounds)     object - 
Review             object' does this mean that weight has some non float arguments?

Comment: @StefanoPozzi - What is your pandas version?

Comment: @StefanoPozzi - `object` means it is obviously string column.

Comment: version = 0.22.0  / I tried using this -> pd.to_numeric(df['Weight(Pounds)'])  but doesn't seem to make any change (still object)

Comment: @StefanoPozzi - Do you need `df['Weight(Pounds)'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Weight(Pounds)'], errors='coerce')` ?

Comment: check my answer, last paragraph.

Comment: I added the error argument and it correctly converts to float64: 'Brand              object - 
Name               object - 
NumsHelpful       float64 - 
Rating            float64 - 
Weight(Pounds)    float64 - 
Review             object' but the error still persists ('TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found')

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen because when creating the index you chose to  keep the column in the list, usually the column goes to the index is excluded from the table, so do the following:

```
# dataset_A was created with the option # drop = False
df_dataset_new = dataset_A.copy()
index_df = ['month', 'scop']
```

```
# dataset_new will be create`enter code here`d with the option # drop = True
df_dataset_new.set_index(index_df, drop=True, inplace=True, verify_integrity=True)
```